# The ViewModel returned after the Create View is Empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a create view :-

```
@model MvcCommons.ViewModels.CompositeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Article</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleTitle)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleTitle)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleTitle)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleText)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleText)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleText)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleSource)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleSource)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleSource)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.CategoryID, "Category")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.CategoryID)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

and in the controller I have the following :-

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CompositeViewModel viewModel)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            unitOfWork.ArticleRepository.Insert(viewModel.ArticleViewModel.Article);
            unitOfWork.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        PopulateDropDownList(viewModel.ArticleViewModel.Article.CategoryID);
        return View(viewModel);

    }
```

The CompositeViewModel is as follows :-

```
 public class CompositeViewModel
{
    public ImageViewModel ImageViewModel;
    public ArticleViewModel ArticleViewModel;
    public ProjectViewModel ProjectViewModel;

    public CompositeViewModel()
    {
        ImageViewModel = new ImageViewModel();
        ArticleViewModel = new ArticleViewModel();
        ProjectViewModel = new ProjectViewModel();
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I click on the Create link, and go into the Controllers's Action, the  CompositeViewModel viewModel is empty.

Can anyone tell me why, I cannot seem to figure out why.

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: AFAIK , for complex objects MVC cannot update the model through form values, so you need to get `FormCollection coll` in the create `POST` action and fill the model using form values submitted.

Comment: @Furqan i must disagree, i am using complex objects and the model binder automatically binds them to the model at post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the model set your existing fields as propreties and don`t use the constructor because on each model instantiation it will create  new members: Example:

```
 public class CompositeViewModel
 {
    public ImageViewModel ImageViewModel { get; set; };
    public ArticleViewModel ArticleViewModel{ get; set; };
    public ProjectViewModel ProjectViewModel{ get; set; };
 }
```

Comment: This does not work, since in the Index Action, I have viewModel.ArticleViewModel.CategoryID = SelectedCategory.GetValueOrDefault(); and the ViewModel.ArticleViewModel is not instantiated

Comment: thats because you need to instantiate the model yourself and fill it with the desired data on the GET method.

Comment: yes correct, I instatiated the model inside the Index Action.  Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to get the CategoryID though, its always 0 no matter what I choose.  Isn't it supposed to be populated inside the Article property?

Comment: No, for example if you use Entity framework whe you use its add method it will auto increment the Id, else you must add in your view something like this @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.YourId); so it will keep the value and make it available on post as well.

Comment: However the CategoryID is a dropdownlist (@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", String.Empty)) which I am populating in the GET, and normally in the POST, I would get the Value inside the Article property. when I was working with only 1 viewModel (article), it was working fine.  Now I have included the CompositeViewModel because of the Images and it stopped working

Comment: I can tell you this, be carefull, in a dropdownlist the value is not the same as the text. Anyway if you have a new question its better to post a new one as it no longer enters in the scope of the previous one.